# High frequency refresh telerik radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

On a winform application,I've the following scenario:

1. A socket receives data with high frequency (150-200packets x second )
2. I've a grid view that is populated on the decoded packet received
3. the received item can be a new item or an update of a previous one..there're 5possible value that can be updated
4. the gridview is in virtualization mode : on

Since I can't bind to a BindingList (it will freeze the Ui thread) I've decided to use a Queue and to update the grid view based on a Timer. When the timer's elapsed event is processed I update the gridview calling the
     gridview.TemplateMaster.Refresh() causing the cellValueNeeded to be called

This is the fastest solution I've found but I have some problems:

1. I can't know which column has been updated
2. Using the virtualization on cause me to call the cellValueNeeded each time and my List is almost useless, I can use it as a bi dimensional array
3. I've to custom implement sort/filter/column reorder

Anyone of you has got a better approach ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried to use the BindingList? The control's `ListChanged` event reacts to individual cell value changes and should not be re-binding the entire list. I would expect it to be optimized for your situation and therefore quite fast. Quick look here: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-bindinglist.html I mean, that's why we pay money for advanced controls like this... If Telerik's grid chokes on this level of data I would suggest shopping around for a different grid control.

Comment: Yes using binding list it's a pain... The UI thread goes stucked. ..

Comment: Could you share some parts of your code where ? I have a suspicion that you may be making the grid control work harder than it has to.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following additional information:

> I've got 8 columns... the row number depends of which item is dragged
>   from a treeview... in this test case I've got 256 rows but can be more
>   ...for the second point If I rebing the whole itemsource I loose what
>   has been updated

your issue is much more complex than your OP suggests. You actually have two sources of changes that modify the grid and the underlying data. One is from your incoming data packets and the other is the user. You also have 8*256=2048 items to show the user. That is a lot. And from my understanding of th OP the UI can potentially be updated with as much as 1,000 new values every second. This is not a useful feature since no human being can process information that quickly.

So, given the fact that the user can arbitrarily pull in data into the grid from a tree view and your packet receiver could add or update a thousand cells of grid data per second I would suggest a very different approach:

- Keep the queue collection that holds incoming data
- Add three new pieces of UI just above the grid:

  - A read-only control (simple label control would do) that displays the count of updates currently in the queue
  - A time-stamp of when the grid was last updated from the data packet queue
  - A button which the user would hit manually to pull in the queued data. Clicking the button would reset the time-stamp to *the current time* and the count of queued items to 0
- You could also keep your timer to automatically update the data but make it smarter:

  - Extend the time period between automatic updates
  - Reset the timer whenever the user interacts with the UI at all (this would basically create a situation where the grid is automatically updated only when the user is "idle", or not interacting with the UI)
- The columns being moved around is not a problem since you can find/and refer to columns by their column name rather than their index
- Since the grid can be sorted arbitrarily by the user you need to use a find function to identify the row to update. You should have some sort of (primary/unique) key column, visible or hidden, by which to identify a row and the underlying object
- All other functionality stays the same

**Original answer for posterity:**

I suggest creating a new collection which would be a shared resource between the UI and your socket thread (assuming you have a thread for the socket communication). You would update this collection as well as a flag time-stamp of the latest change. This flag is important because you would not change it unless data did actually change. You could also have an additional field which could count the number of updates since the latest change. (I'm assuming/hoping that much of this data coming in would not actually be different.)

So now you have an internal cache that can be shared by both threads. You don't have to worry about synchronization issues because one thread only writes and the other only reads.

Comment: I've got 8 columns... the row number depends of which item is dragged from a treeview... in this test case I've got 256 rows but can be more ...for the second point If I rebing the whole itemsource I loose what has been updated

Comment: @advapi: Your issue is much more complex than your OP suggests. You should update your OP with the info from your comment above. It is very important. That said, you actually have two sources that modify the grid and the underlying data. One is from your packets and the other is the user. You also have 8*256=2048 items to show the user. That is a lot. (continued in my edited answer above)

Comment: In the truth not all the cells are updated at the same time... I've as I call it some storm in the startup... After the updates are few